# Why do I need to call zone.run() here?

Tags: angular

So, I am writing some angular stuff. And I am running into a problem that I want to understand better. I know that some of you all will understand this, but I can't, for the life of me, understand why this works this way.

First, look at the code. 
[image: Here is my app component]

Here are my first two questions.

1. In my `ngOnInit` handler, I subscribe to an Rx.Observable... and I want to know why the `*ngIf` in the template doesn't update unless I do a `zone.run()` manually. Is this normal? Or is something weird here. I would expect this to simply work.
2. When I tried to inject the zone into my `AppComponent#constructor` I got runtime errors about not knowing how to resolve the parameters to my app component. So I had to add the `@Inject(NgZone)` to the beginning. Not sure why it didn't simply work and inject it without the `@Inject` syntax being added. Anyone know what-about-what there?

Comment: It's to trigger change detection, it's like $scope.digest() in angularjs.

Comment: It seems like `CurrentUser$` is emitting value from outside context of Angular(perhaps some custom event), where zonejs can't monkey patch it. It would be better if you can add `CurrentUser$` code & how it emits an value to its subscription ? If it is custom event then you have to run *Change Detection* manually to update your binding

Comment: @PankajParkar I am pretty sure that is the issue.

Comment: Any idea on why I needed to use @Inject(NgZone) in order to get it to not error on the type of param it was injecting? @PankajParkar

Comment: I don't think there is good explanation for zone:NgZone annotation in particular. @Inject is required when TS is misconfigured and lacks emitDecoratorMetadata option, but this will affect all providers. Considering that NgZone is the only provider in your app, that could be the explanation. Consider providing http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve that can replicate the problems, since it's not clear enough what's going wrong.

Comment: @frosty, what is `CurrentUser$` that you import from `../modules/core/strores`?

Comment: @Maximus it is an Rx.Observable (v4, not v5). It is created outside of the zone. So... that is why, I think.

Comment: @frosty, how do you know that it's created outside the zone? Do you have code for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. I am not sure if it is the only solution, but it makes the most sense to me, after thinking about it for a few days. I think that it issue is that the observable I was subscribed to was created before I imported zone.js. So... I just made the import of `zone.js` to be the first thing done, and then the zone immediately knew about the changes from the observable.

**So the answer is:** Move the `import 'zone.js'` to the top of all of your imports.